# How to Show Blank Image In Crystal report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

By Below Procedure I am Displaying Image to Crystal Report

First:  I created a New Column ("Image") in a datatable of the dataset and change the DataType to System.Byte()

Second : Drag And drop this image Filed Where I want.

```
private void LoadReport()
    {
        frmCheckWeigher rpt = new frmCheckWeigher();
        CryRe_DailyBatch report = new CryRe_DailyBatch();
        DataSet1TableAdapters.DataTable_DailyBatch1TableAdapter ta = new CheckWeigherReportViewer.DataSet1TableAdapters.DataTable_DailyBatch1TableAdapter();
        DataSet1.DataTable_DailyBatch1DataTable table = ta.GetData(clsLogs.strStartDate_rpt, clsLogs.strBatchno_Rpt, clsLogs.cmdeviceid); // Data from Database
        DataTable dt = GetImageRow(table, "Footer.Jpg");

        report.SetDataSource(dt);
        crv1.ReportSource = report;
        crv1.Refresh();

    }
```

// By this Function I merge My Image data into dataTable

```
private DataTable GetImageRow(DataTable dt, string ImageName)
    {

        try
        {

            FileStream fs;
            BinaryReader br;

            if (File.Exists(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + ImageName))
            {
                fs = new FileStream(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + ImageName, FileMode.Open);
            }
            else
            {
                // if photo does not exist show the Blank Space or Show Nothing 
               for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                      dt.Rows[i]["Image"] = DBNull.Value  ;

                }
                return dt; 
            }
            // initialise the binary reader from file streamobject 
            br = new BinaryReader(fs);
            // define the byte array of filelength 
            byte[] imgbyte = new byte[fs.Length + 1];
            // read the bytes from the binary reader 
            imgbyte = br.ReadBytes(Convert.ToInt32((fs.Length)));

                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                     dt.Rows[i]["Image"] = imgbyte;

                }


            br.Close();
            // close the binary reader 
            fs.Close();
            // close the file stream 




        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // error handling 
            MessageBox.Show("Missing " + ImageName + " in application folder");
        }
        return dt;
        // Return Datatable After Image Row Insertion

    }
```

this Works Perfectly when I have Image on  path but 
I want to Show Empty- blank Space when user Not Give Image on Specify path,
But I get blank Square as per given Image with border how to remove it please help me ..
[image]

Comment: I have no experience in C# but you may need to try `supress` option to supress when the used doesn't give any path.. Something like check `ISNull(path) and if it is true supress the image else display`

Comment: Open the report in Crystal designer, try right clicking the image, then click `Format`. Check to see if there's a border set.

Answer (score 2):

Use the suppress function from the report it self,

> Right click on the image object >> format object >> Fill the check box near the word suppress then click on the formula on the right of suppress then add the formula you require some thing like:

```
ISNULL({Class;1.Img})
```