# Show 'None in picture' when report (table) is empty in Crystal Reports

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

I would like to know how to display the image 'Nothing' when there is no data on the table, here is a picture of what I would like to do on crystal reports

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use suppress property of image. Add formula like below that if no-result suppress false else suppress true.

```
ISNULL({Class;1.Img})
```

See this link [How to Show Blank Image In Crystal report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24093921/how-to-show-blank-image-in-crystal-report)

Comment: what happened with you, what you implemented and what does not work

Comment: Hello, I get this errror "this field name is not known"

Comment: you have to replace your field name

Comment: Yes but the picture is not a field

Comment: obviously, in your detail section of group section, set the condition as above link. please follow the step as above link